# Windbg scripting - echo the class type of a variable

Tags: class, types, scripting, windbg

In Windbg I have a script that iterates through the frames of a stack and does a good job of pulling back things of interest, echoing them to the Command Window (it just sniffs things out that could require further investigation).

In certain frames, there will be a `this` that I'm interested in some details of. I can certainly extract the details fine, but I'd like to get the actual class type from it too. I know that if I then do a `dv /t` I will see something like the following:

```
0:115> .frame 14
0:115> dv /t
class foo1 * this = 0x00000000e9ed0010
```

I would like a way of being able to pass just `foo1` to a `.printf` command.

In frames that have more than simply `this`, I can restrict output by using the pattern `dv /t this` obviously, but is there a good way of having something like what follows in a frame and me being able to extract just `foo1`?

```
0:115> .frame 17
0:115> dv /t
class foo1 * this = 0x00000000f3e2f568
class foo2 * bar2 = 0x0000000000000001
bool _somebool = true
```

Doing what follows is very close to the limited output I'd like... but I just want to neaten it up.

```
0:115> .frame 17
0:115> dv /t this
class foo1 * this = 0x00000000f3e2f568
```

Following the example code from blabb:

```
0:000> dv /t
class Time * this = 0x001efb24
int h = 0n23
int m = 0n59
int s = 0n59
0:000> dv /t this
class Time * this = 0x001efb24
0:000> some command
Time
```

The third command is what I'm looking for.

Comment: This third command I was looking for could happily be something like this - `.foreach /pS 1 /ps 4 (Token {dv /t this}) { .printf "${Token}" }`.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is: you need a command that takes `foo1` as a parameter and gives an output like `dv /t` but just for all `foo1`.

IMHO, it's hardly possible with builtin WinDbg functionality. You could fiddle around with `.foreach` inculding `$spat` and the like.

One possibility is `.shell` along with the command line tool `findstr` or Cygwin `grep`. But that's not convenient, because it always outputs `Process started` etc. You could again work around this using `.foreach` and skipping some tokens, but that's tedious.

There are `grep` implementations for WinDbg such as [long123king's grep plugin](https://github.com/long123king/grep) and if I recall correctly, there's also a grep implementation in [PDE](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21AJeSzeiu8SQ7T4w&id=DAE128BD454CF957%217152&cid=DAE128BD454CF957).

Then there is [pykd](/questions/tagged/pykd), which has the powers of Python and let's you do basically anything.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure i understand what you need
but have you given the new dx expression evaluator a try

for example

```
0:000> dv /t
class Time * this = 0x001efb24
int h = 0n23
int m = 0n59
int s = 0n59
0:000> dv /t this
class Time * this = 0x001efb24
0:000> dx @$curstack.Frames[0].LocalVariables
@$curstack.Frames[0].LocalVariables                
    this             : 0x1efb24 [Type: Time *]
0:000> dx @$curstack.Frames[0].LocalVariables.this
@$curstack.Frames[0].LocalVariables.this                 : 0x1efb24 [Type: Time *]
    [+0x000] hour             : 23 [Type: int]
    [+0x004] minute           : 59 [Type: int]
    [+0x008] second           : 59 [Type: int]
```

you can enhance this with javascript  to fine tune it to you needs

here is how you can enhance this with javascript

make a file `whateverfoo.js` with contents below

```
function log(logstr) {
    return host.diagnostics.debugLog(logstr + "\n")
}
function locvartgttyp(frameno)
{
    log( host.currentThread.Stack.Frames[frameno].LocalVariables.this.targetType.name)
}
```

and use it like

```
:\>echo %wdbg%
"c:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x86\cdb.exe"

:\>%wdbg% time.exe

Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.17763.132 X86

0:000> g time!main

time!main:
01237a80 55              push    ebp
0:000> tc;t

time!Time::Time:
01231140 55              push    ebp

0:000> dv /t
class Time * this = 0x00000002
int h = 0n23
int m = 0n59
int s = 0n59

0:000> .load jsprovider

0:000> .scriptload c:\wdscr\locvar.js

JavaScript script successfully loaded from 'c:\wdscr\locvar.js'

0:000> dx @$scriptContents.locvartgttyp(0)
Time *

@$scriptContents.locvartgttyp(0)
0:000>
```

Comment: What I unserstood is that he needs a command that takes `foo1` as a parameter, not `this`.

Comment: I edited my question to illustrate what I'd been wanting; apologies if my initial question was not clear enough.

Comment: i am still not sure of your intention i hope you understand Time * ! = Time  any way i added a javascript enhancement as i earlier replied take a look